# hot pack experiment: calcium chloride vs magnesium chloride

Tags: enthalpy

why is calcium chloride preferred in hot packs even though magnesium chloride produces higher negative enthalpy? Experiment performed at school shows higher temperature change and more quicker increase in temperature with calcium chloride than with magnesium chloride. However, on a theoretical basis, magnesium chloride has a higher negative enthalpy. How to explain this?

Comment: The site expects that you write explicit compact summary of your prior effort to answer the question, based on your knowledge and on searching for existing related  info or answers. It would prevent others to tell you what you already know or what you could easily find yourself.

Comment: Please use proper punctuation.

Comment: The enthalpy of formation has nothing to do with the enthalpy that you have measured. Both are independent parameters. One may be big and the other tiny, or the contrary. What you have measured is the enthalpy of hydration (or of dissolution). It is not the enthalpy of formation.

Comment: Thanks. Is the higher negative enthalpy for MgCl2 an enthalpy of hydration or formation? Why is calcium chloride preferred in hot packs? Is there more factors such as availability or cost in play than just an effective chemical process?

Answer (score 1):

$\ce{MgCl2}$ formation enthalpy is for $\ce{Mg(s) + Cl2(g) -> MgCl2(s)}$.

Its hydration enthalpy is for $\ce{Mg^2+(g) + 2 Cl-(g) ->[H2O]Mg^2+(aq) + 2 Cl-(aq)}$

Its lattice formation enthalpy is for $\ce{Mg^2+(g) + 2 Cl-(g) ->MgCl2(s)}$

Its dissolution enthalpy is for $\ce{MgCl2(s) -> Mg^2+(g) + 2 Cl-(g) ->[H2O]Mg^2+(aq) + 2 Cl-(aq)}$

For the heat pack, the dissolution enthalpy is what you need.

Highly negative salt formation enthalpy means they is highly negative lattice formation enthalpy too, what increases value of salt dissolution enthalpy and decreases released heat.